# KendoUI Grid column autosizing

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, autosize

I'm trying to create a grid which would has to have auto-sizing columns (within some constraints) and its width must never exceed the width of parent div.

I have 4 columns:

```
       col1        col2    col3    col4
------------------------------------------
| very long text |  ...  |  ...  |  ...  |
|     ...        |  ...  |  ...  |  ...  |
------------------------------------------
```

The values in first column are very long so I'm using styling: `white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;` the text stays in one line. I want `col2` to be 105-170px, `col3` 40-190px and `col4` 75-150px. I like to keep it as small as possible to avoid huge white spaces which appear.

I know that something like this can be achieved by setting `scrollable: true`, but I don't need scrollbar and I really don't like how it sits there for no good use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing with different options and hours of searching I've decided to use a little less elegant solution, but I've achieved what I was looking for. If someone faces similar problem, here is what I did:

- When the DOM loads (`$(document).ready(...)` or `$(...)` in jQuery), I call code to remove right `padding-right` of `.k-grid-header` and remove `overflow-y` of `.k-grid-content`.

The code I've used:

```
// jQuery code
$(".k-grid-header").css("padding-right","0");
$(".k-grid-content").css("overflow-y","initial");

// JS (without jQuery) equivalent
var gridHeaders = document.querySelectorAll(".k-grid-header");
for (var i = 0, element; element = gridHeaders[i++];)
    element.paddingRight = "0";

var gridContent = document.querySelectorAll(".k-grid-content");
for (var i = 0, element; element = gridContent [i++];)
    element.overflowY = "initial";
```